# UI Button is nil, obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, I'm trying to set the `tag` of my button equal to the `indexPath.row`. However, the button is `nil` and therefore the `tag` is `nil`.

Anyone know why? It's a button that I made in the cell of a view controller.

EDIT: My postCell isn't nil. Only the button associated with the cell is nil 
AND 
I tried to alloc and init the favoriteButton in the VolunteerOpportunityCell, specifically in the awakeFromNib method. But it doesn't allow me to call the alloc method.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code in `code block` and not as a picture.

Comment: it means your button is not connected in your Cell nib file

Comment: What is my cell nib file? The button in storyboard is connected to the button property if  that's what you mean. @ShauketSheikh

Comment: TroubleShooting steps, First of All check your button connected inside storyboard with your Cell or not. Then verify your resuseable identifier "postCell" is setup in your storyboard. use this code to deque your cell.

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! yourcustomcell
    cell.yourbutton.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: Once you fix your issue with your button, keep in mind that using tags to track index path is far from ideal. There are proper solutions for determining which button was tapped.

Comment: @rmaddy What are some of those solutions and are they easier to implement than tags?

Comment: Easier is not relevant. Tags can work but they have very specific limitations. It's better to use one of several other possible solutions that don't suffer from the same limitations. The solution depends on how you are using the button. This is all beyond the scope of this question which is focused on your button being `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. It can return `nil`, in which case your `postCell` is `nil` and everything connected with it is `nil`. You are not checking to see if it *is* nil, so you clearly do not understand this basic fact about how `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` works. But that's okay, because you should not be calling it in the first place.

Instead, call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. It will *never* be `nil`. It will provide a cell, and now you stand a chance of being able to configure that cell.

Comment: My postCell isn't nil. Only the button associated with the cell is nil

Comment: @EzraBekele Your button should be connected to UI element on xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your `reuse id` to see whether the registered `reuse id` is `@"postCell"`. If so, make sure the `favoritedButton` is properly assigned. That is to say, if the cell is initialized from .xib file, check the connection; If not, check where the `favoritedButton` is created.

Answer (score 0):

The first point,please check how to create this `VolunteerOpportunityCell` class.Of course,in objective-c has two method that .xib file or handwriting code.So you should know both different in load method.
I create a test project to confirm my answer.
I think you use .xib file to creat this `favoriteButton`.you can do this.

```
  VoulunteerOpportunityCell *postCell = (VoulunteerOpportunityCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"postCell"];
if (postCell == nil) {
    postCell = [[VoulunteerOpportunityCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"postCell"];
    NSArray *nib =[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"VoulunteerOpportunityCell" owner:self options:nil];
    postCell = (VoulunteerOpportunityCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

postCell.tag = indexPath.row;
postCell.favoritedButton.tag = indexPath.row;
NSLog(@"indexPath.row-%ld,post.tag:%ld",indexPath.row,postCell.favoritedButton.tag);
```

So you can paste my code to have a try!

if you use handwriting code,you must init `favoritedButton` in `VoulunteerOpportunityCell`

Comment: I tried to alloc and init the favoriteButton in the VolunteerOpportunityCell, specifically in the awakeFromNib method. But it doesn't allow me to call the alloc method.

Comment: So where are you initializing? You need know only use .xib or .nib file can effect that  `awakeFromNib` method. So you handwriting code,please alloc init this button in `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` method.If your problem still happen,please add breakpoint in Debug mode.And send complete code to here.